# Force align a content in center

Tags: css, html, center

I have some content which will contain some divisions, labels, forms in it. I want to force them in the center of page. How can I do this?

Note: I tried using `<div align="center">`, `<center>` but nothing works?

Comment: We all need more code. Please Write all the html snippet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your content doesn't have a fixed width do this:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="inner">some content</div>
</div>


.content
{
 text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

If it does, you could do this:

```
.content
{
 width: xpx;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me from big trouble.

Comment: Awesome, it helped in 2018 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
div {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">testing text align</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use margin (auto) to center the div but it must have a width.

[W3School - Center Aligning Using the margin Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)