# How to center vertical `tab-content` without the tablist?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Given the form below, I need to center only the fields and keep the nav buttons where they are. In other words, only `tab-content` to be centered, without the `tablist`s.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="h-100">
    <div class="rounded-lg d-block d-sm-flex">
        <div class="profile-tab-nav border-right">
            <div class="p-4">
                <img class="rounded-circle" style="width: 100px" alt="Avatar"
                     src={{ request.user.profile.photo.url }}/>
            </div>
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile-tab-panel" role="tab"
                   aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-universal-access text-center mr-1"></i>
                    Profile
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="security-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#security-tab-panel" role="tab"
                   aria-controls="security" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-shield text-center mr-1"></i>
                    Security
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" class="row" placeholder="First name">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" class="row" placeholder="Last name">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried

```
<div class="tab-content" style="flex-direction: column" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

and

```
<div class="tab-content" style="float: right" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

and

```
<div class="tab-content" style="align-content: center; align-self: center; align-items: center" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

and

```
<div class="tab-content justify-content-sm-center" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

and what is suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785752/force-align-a-content-in-center), nothing is working, all lead to the same location, aligned to the left with half the page empty. The only solution that seems to be working is by hard coding a left margin, which is not a flexible solution and won't fit all screen sizes.

Comment: I added a form, I need the form to be in the center and the nav buttons to remain in the same place and size

Comment: Do you have a reference picture of what it should look like?

Comment: the form fields need to be in the center of the page and the buttons to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex works by having a Flex container with Flex items inside. So you can keep your container inside `section` as the Flex container. I removed the other classes because they don't do anything.

```
<div class="d-sm-flex">
```

Your `nav` don't need any Flex classes, it will automatically behave as a Flex item. (PS `.border-right` does not exists, it's `.border-end`)

```
 <div class="profile-tab-nav border-end">
```

Since `.tab-content` is also a Flex item you can apply `.flex-grow-1` to let it take up all the remaining width inside the Flex container (since default `flex-direction` is `row`). Then we apply `.text-center` to center its content horizontally.

```
<div class="tab-content text-center flex-grow-1" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

Another option is making it a flex container itself and use `.justify-content-center`:

```
 <div class="tab-content d-flex justify-content-center flex-grow-1" id="v-pills-tabContent">
```

**Example below**

Note: the `nav` doesn't work and since it was not a part of your question I left it as is.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section>
  <div class="d-sm-flex">
    <div class="profile-tab-nav border-end">
      <div class="p-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" style="width: 100px" alt="Avatar" src={{ request.user.profile.photo.url }} />
      </div>
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile-tab-panel" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">
          <i class="fa fa-universal-access text-center mr-1"></i> Profile
        </a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="security-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#security-tab-panel" role="tab" aria-controls="security" aria-selected="false">
          <i class="fa fa-shield text-center mr-1"></i> Security
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content text-center flex-grow-1" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>
          <input type="text" class="row" placeholder="First name">
        </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
          <input type="text" class="row" placeholder="Last name">
        </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
          <input type="email" class="row" placeholder="Email">
        </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```